# Command Logging in Linux

Tags: linux, logs

I am seeking guidance on how to set up logging for executed Linux commands into a designated log file with specific details. My objective is to create a mechanism, possibly a daemon or background script, that records user-executed commands in a specified logfile.

I have explored the use of auditd, but it provides more detailed information than what I require. Specifically, I am interested in capturing limited details such as the username, timestamp, and executed command.

Could anyone provide insights, suggestions, or code examples on how to achieve this logging functionality in a Linux environment?

Comment: [Please do not cross-post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/64069/355310). For the record, the other copy is [on Super User](https://superuser.com/q/1835834/432690).

Comment: Have you looked at `last`?

Comment: Just use auditd & ignore the part you have no interest in.

Comment: https://serverfault.com/questions/25595/bash-shell-session-logging-on-remote-host  .. however, bare in mind that they can undo anything you did if you grant them root via `sudo` ...

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: You found an answer to your query but it provides too much information so you disregard it? /smh  I suggest you consider learning a bit about receiving, processing, and manipulating text streams. You have everything you need at your finger tips, including the MAN pages for sed, awk, cut, and Bash read/while/for command loops.

Answer (score -1):

`~/.bash_history` already logs all the commands for you. Your program could wait until a change in `bash_history`, whilst also recording the time. When there is a change, grab it, and place it into a different logfile with the time at which the change happened. You could also place the username in by using the `whoami` command or the `$USER` variable.

Comment: Users don't have to use `bash`, and if they do they can configure it to either save it's history to another file, or not put certain commands in the history at all, so there are many things that could stop this approach from working.

Comment: True. Unless the OP wanted this to work out the box, I suppose it could ask the user for path to their `bash_history`? However I suppose that could be quite unprofessional method.